# Joining multiple tables and getting multiple attributes from one of them

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to join multiple tables together for building a report. The report lists a course, revisions made to it, and who requested, made and approved the revisions.

Under requested, made an approved, the values are employee numbers. I'm trying to join my innerjoined table above, with the Employee table so I can list the names (not just employee numbers) of those that requested, made and approved revisions.

This is what I have which I know is totally wrong.

```
SELECT *
FROM Courses 
INNER JOIN CourseRevisions ON CourseRevisions.PELID = Courses.PELID
INNER JOIN CourseGroups ON CourseGroups.CourseGroupID = Courses.CourseGroupID
INNER JOIN [dbo].[OPG_Employees] ON OPG_Employees.EmployeeID = CourseRevisions.UpdatedBy
AND OPG_Employees.EmployeeID = CourseRevisions.ApprovedBy
AND OPG_Employees.EmployeeID = CourseRevisions.RequestedBy
```

This only returns a single result which just happens to have the same employee ID listed for all 3 (Requested, Approved and Updated)

How would i get it so I can get the table result for individual employees in each?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to join to the OPG_Employees table once for each field, i.e. 3 times in the example above. One INNER JOIN to it for UpdatedBy, one INNER JOIN for ApprovedBy, one INNER JOIN for RequestedBy.

Something like so:

```
SELECT *
FROM Courses 
INNER JOIN CourseRevisions ON CourseRevisions.PELID = Courses.PELID
INNER JOIN CourseGroups ON CourseGroups.CourseGroupID = Courses.CourseGroupID
INNER JOIN [dbo].[OPG_Employees] empUpdatedBy ON empUpdatedBy.EmployeeID = CourseRevisions.UpdatedBy
INNER JOIN [dbo].[OPG_Employees] empApprovedBy ON empApprovedBy.EmployeeID = CourseRevisions.ApprovedBy
INNER JOIN [dbo].[OPG_Employees] empRequestedBy ON empRequestedBy.EmployeeID = CourseRevisions.RequestedBy
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a separate join for each employee being referenced:

```
SELECT *
FROM Courses INNER JOIN
     CourseRevisions
     ON CourseRevisions.PELID = Courses.PELID INNER JOIN
     CourseGroups
     ON CourseGroups.CourseGroupID = Courses.CourseGroupID INNER JOIN
     [dbo].[OPG_Employees] UpdateEmp 
     ON UpdateEmp.EmployeeID = CourseRevisions.UpdatedBy INNER JOIN
     [dbo].[OPG_Employees] ApprovedEmp
     on OPG_ApprovedEmp.EmployeeID = CourseRevisions.ApprovedBy INNER JOIN
     [dbo].[OPG_Employees] RequestedEmp
     on RequestedEmp.EmployeeID = CourseRevisions.RequestedBy
```

Your original formulation required that all three ids be exactly the same.